# Getting different date in jsonFormat from client side at server side in MVC

Tags: c#, datetime, model-view-controller, knockout.js, timezone

I am using Knockout js at client side and MVC C# at server side. I am passing the date in form of **2019-04-25T03:27:00.000Z** (UTC +5:30). on server side i am using DateTime (Used DateTimeOffset, but since same issue i have changed it to DateTime) and getting the different date **{4/25/2019 8:57:00 AM}**.

Problem:
1. If i am changing the timezone of client side system then on server side it always comes the Date with time added with +5.30.

2. I have to ignore the Timestamp on client side or server side both so that i can get exact date what client is sending to server.

Comment: Please write your code as a text, _not_ as an image. Imgur was blocked on my country (Turkey) over years, for example.

Comment: Well imgur not blocked in my country, but I prefer to read (may be copy) from actual text.

Comment: @SeM, Of course, code examples should be _textual_. I just wanna give an example.

Comment: Basically there no complex code. I am just passing date from client side in JsonFormat like

jsonData.elementPermission.RightsExpirationDate()
Thu Apr 25 2019 14:26:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

and on backend side there is an API which is getting the data. on the model there is property  
public DateTime? RightsExpirationDate { get; set; }

Thanks

Comment: This only happen when my client and server has different time zone.

Comment: if you want to ignore timestamp just split it(`T`) & remove or  try to follow UTC standard even while you save to db so you won't mess up with dates/timestamp(best practice) @SatyamPrakash

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, so this is probably what is going on:

DateTime has a "Kind" property that indicates whether the date/time is local, UTC, or "unknown".  When the controller method has a DateTime parameter, it sets it to the appropriate value with a "Kind" value of "Local".  In other words, it is the same time as the client transmitted, but offset by the timezone.

To get back to UTC on the server, use the DateTime ToUniveralTime() method.  Note that this will only work correctly if the DateTime Kind value is either Local or Utc.

Example:

```
public void GetDateRangeReadings(DateTime startDate)
{
    startDate = startDate.ToUniversalTime();
```